# How do I stop the multiple form submissions?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

`<a title=@VirtuaDeskPortal.Resources.SectionTitle.Submit href="#" class="BlueBg" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" id="submit">@VirtuaDeskPortal.Resources.SectionTitle.Submit</a>`

Once we submit the form we are creating a ticket. If we click multiple times, duplicate tickets are being created. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get rid of the `onclick` in the tag. Then have a script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var submitted = false;

    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!submitted) {
            submitted = true;
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    });
});
```